# Expectation of Gaussian random vector & arbitrary function thereof?

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, gaussian

I saw in a paper (https://www.princeton.edu/~wbialek/rome/refs/bialek+ruyter_05.pdf Eq.37) the following identity:

[image]

where the <.> operator refers to a population average.

No source or justification was given for this identity & they seemed to assume the reader should be familiar with it.

However, I have no idea where they got this or how to proove it....

Any help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Smells like an integration by parts argument, applied to what one gets from multiplying out the LHS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

indeed, integration by parts does the trick:

$$\int d\mathbf{x}\; \mathbf{x} \,f(\mathbf{x})\exp\left(-\tfrac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{C}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{x}\right)=-\int d\mathbf{x}\;  \,f(\mathbf{x})\,\mathbf{C}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\exp\left(-\tfrac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{C}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{x}\right)$$
$$=\int d\mathbf{x}\;  \,\exp\left(-\tfrac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{C}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{x}\right)\mathbf{C}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\, f(\mathbf{x})$$
$$\Rightarrow\left\langle\mathbf{x}\,f(\mathbf{x})\right\rangle=\mathbf{C}\cdot\left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}}f(\mathbf{x})\right\rangle$$
where I have used that $\mathbf{C}$ is a symmetric matrix

Comment: Thank you Carlo. One question: why does the 'uv' part of integration by parts vanish? (here $u*v=\mathbf{C}f(\mathbf{x})\exp\left(-\tfrac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{C}^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{x}\right)$)

Comment: you have to evaluate this boundary term at infinity, where it vanishes exponentially fast (assuming f(x) does not blow up at infinity, but then the average is not defined)

Answer (score 2):

This is the famous [Stein's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_lemma) and indeed integration by parts is how you prove it!